# How pass 4 string values from HTML page to a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, string, html

Wish to pass 4 string values (not user inputted) from a HTML page to a javascript function in a separate file.

Have some javascript code which does an image flip.  I've used this on many HTML pages and it worked.

Now I wish to put this code in a separate file, called "image-flip-comment.js" and each webpage will pass it 4 string values. The script will execute the function which will be displayed in the HTML page.

This is PART of the working code which was from a script on my HTML page.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- hide from non-JavaScript Browsers
Image_top1= new Image(100,100)
Image_top1.src = "../buttons/Rm_btn_fwa.gif"
//----more stuff ----

function SwapOutTop() {
document.imagebacktop.src = Image_top1.src; return true;
}
// - stop hiding -->
</script>


// here is PART of my code from the file  "image-flip-comment.js"

// Imageflip Javascript routine, version w passed values shown as comments
// <!-- hide from non-JavaScript Browsers  I'm going to assume this is 
obsolete?  

Image_top1= new Image(100,100)
Image_top1.src = "../buttons/${button_forw_a}!"
// Rm_btn_fwa.gif this went on above line

// more stuff for the other 3 parameters
function FwSwapBackTop() {
document.imagefliptop.src = Image_top1.src; return true;
}
```

Comment: btw, `<!-- hide from non-JavaScript Browsers` needs the end of the comment at the end like `-->`.

Comment: I don't undestand the problem can't you just call the function and add the 4 strings as parameters?

Comment: That's what I want to do, call the function and pass it the 4 parameters as strings.  How to do this is my question.  I need to know where in my HTML I should put the call for the javascript and how to format the 4 strings to pass it.                            
  Then for the javascript I need to know how to read the 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can have a parameterized function like

```
function imageflip(var your_parameter_name) {
...
...<!-- access the string here -->
...
}
```

And depending upon the event you want your image to flip call the function by onclick with parameter passed

For example:

```
<a onclick="imageflip('some_string_value')" >click</a>
```

Comment: this is what I want to do  <br>  I think your 1st code is for the js fcn although I don't think <!-- access the string here --> will work.      This is also html comment format in a javascript file, it won't work.      Your   2nd comment appears to be html.  Where does it go?